# Need to migrate a 15GB list with attachments. How?

Tags: 2007, list, migration, attachments, 2003

I have a 15GB list with attachments that I need to migrate from SP2003 to SP2007.  Can anyone suggest a solution which will keep my list and attachments intact?

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use the migrate content database approach. check this technet:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263299(v=office.12).aspx

or i would recommend to buy a 3rd party tool to migration. As per my personal experience i would recommend ShareGate.
http://en.share-gate.com/

```
OR there are several other tools available in market
Tsunami migration tool
QUEST
AVEPOINT
METALOGIX
```